# how to further specify a sqlite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to SQL and was wondering if there is a way to futher refine my query. For example i have a table with student names and their grades and i want to find the student's name with the highest grade. I came as far as

```
SELECT name FROM students ORDER BY grade DESC
```

but that returns all the names. I thought of using LIMIT, but for ex., if 2 students have the same highest grade, I would like them both to be returned.

Is there a way?

Comment: Why the enormous bounty?

Comment: @boisvert because FREEEEEEDOM!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that this will work with sqlite.

```
select name from students where grade = (select max(grade) from students);
```

Comment: I should report this shady under the table rep exchange.

Answer (score 1):

It is not mentioned that name is a Primary Key or not so it is better to use it like this(Not assuming name as PK):

```
select distinct name from students where grade = (select max(grade) from students);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do as follows :)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
    Name,
    Grade,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Grade desc) AS BestGrade
FROM
    students
) SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE BestGrade = 1
```

Comment: I can't find anything in the SQLite documentation to indicate that it supports analytical functions.

Comment: You might be right, I didn't notice the sqllite tag..sorry about this. This statement works with microsft sql server 2005 and above

Comment: How to make the simple complicated :)

Comment: "Complicated" but yes I see your point. My point however was just to give an alternative solution so you as a developer can see the options that are out there :)